Search for the individual values from Sheet1 column B looking in sheet2 column B, and replace sheet1 value
I need help writing a VBA macro that will search for the individual values from Sheet1 column B looking in sheet2 column B, and replace the sheet1 value with the associated value in sheet 2 column C. In other words, take value in sheet1 B2 and search for same value in Sheet2 column B. When found, take value in Column C right next to it and replace sheet1 B2 with the value found in sheet2 Column C. Thanks in advance for the help!
I was trying to use the code below, but the item replacement line (marked with-->) is not working for some reason, I keep getting a

run-time error 13: type mismatch

but can't figure out wat I did wrong.
    Dim wb As Workbook, firstWs As Worksheet, secondWs As Worksheet
    Dim matchIndex As Integer

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set firstWs = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Set secondWs = wb.Worksheets(2)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' We'll start at i=2 to account for the header
    For i = 2 To firstWs.Range("A2:A2000").Rows.Count
        On Error Resume Next
        ' MATCH will find the row number in sheet 2 - change the range specifications as needed
        matchIndex = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(firstWs.Range("B" & i), secondWs.Range("B2:B3000"), 0)
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0

        ' MATCH will throw an error if it finds no results.
        ' Hence: if matchindex contains an error, do nothing.
        ' But if it doesn't contain an error, it must contain a row number - so we can proceed.
        If Not Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(matchIndex) Then
    -->     firstWs.Range("B" + i).Value = secondWs("C" + matchIndex).Value
        End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


Use & for concatenation, not +. Looks like you're missing a Range too

Side note: it seems easier to use Application.Match and IsError, see this.

firstWs.Range("A2:A2000").Rows.Count is 1999, not 2000, btw.

Have you considered writing both ranges to arrays, processing the data by walking the arrays and then writing the array for secondws back to Excel?  It sounds like a time-consuming process, but since you're using arrays in memory, it's REALLY fast.

@Alex; did you try my offer below?

You can use VLOOKUP here:
Sub Tester()
    Dim wb As Workbook, firstWs As Worksheet, secondWs As Worksheet
    Dim res, v, i As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set firstWs = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Set secondWs = wb.Worksheets(2)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 2 To 2000 'start at 2 to skip header
        With firstWs.Range("B" & i)
            v = .Value
            If Len(v) > 0 Then 'anything to look up?
                res = Application.VLookup(v, secondWs.Range("B2:C3000"), 2, False) 'no `.WorksheetFunction`
                If Not IsError(res) Then .Value = res 'if no match, `res` will be an error value
            End If
        End With
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


That is great, but that still doesn't replace the value back into sheet 1, my problem is that I couldn't get the associated value in sheet2 column C to rewrite the original search value in Sheet1 column B

If Not IsError(res) Then .Value = res puts res into colB on firstWs.  Did you try it?

Yeah I did try it, but I need the value in Column C (Next to the found value in Column B) from sheet 2 to go back to sheet 1

Passing 2 to vlookup with a search table range of B2:C3000 returns the value from Col C when the search value is matched in ColB.  That value ends up in res when a match is made, otherwise res gets an error value.

Idk, when I hit run, literally nothing happens. The code runs without any error codes, but no changes to the sheet occur

You'll need to debug your code - maybe it's not finding matches for some reason?

I have worked through debugging it and it is not liking the Vlookup statement and there is an error 2042 on the variable 'res' when I try to show what res is in a msgbox. V was completely fine and it is even iterating through the list correctly, its just that 'res' is not taking the value of the cell in column C...

If the value of v is correct and you're getting an error in res that means the vlookup isn't making a match (or less likely, the cell in Col C on the lookup sheet has an error which then ends up in res).  You will need to figure out why it's not making a match - it might for example to due to some number formatting issues, or the lookup range might be wrong.

Another alternative is using SQL/ADO with VBA to update the table in Sheet1.
So; assuming the table in Sheet1 is something like this;



ID
POSITION
NAME




503
Default
Bob


504
Default
Trevor


501
Default
Susan


502
Default
Mary


506
Default
David


505
Default
Kyle



and, the table in Sheet2 is;



GENDER
ID
POSITION




Female
501
Manager


Female
502
Asst. Man.


Male
503
Engineer


Male
504
Lawyer


Male
505
Driver


Male
506
Staff



The below code will match the columns labelled as ID in both sheets and will update the data in Sheet1 column labelled as Position with the corresponding data in Sheet2
So, the final table in Sheet1 will be this, after the code is executed;



ID
POSITION
NAME




503
Engineer
Bob


504
Lawyer
Trevor


501
Manager
Susan


502
Asst. Man.
Mary


506
Staff
David


505
Driver
Kyle



VBA code in a standard code module;
Sub Test()
    Dim objConn As Object, strArgs As String, strSQL As String, myFile As String
    
    myFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    
    Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    
    strArgs = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)}; Readonly=False; DBQ=" & myFile
    objConn.Open strArgs
    
    strSQL = " Update [" & myFile & "].[Sheet1$] As T1 " & _
             " Left Join " & _
             " [Sheet2$] As T2 " & _
             " On T1.[ID] = T2.[ID] " & _
             " Set T1.[POSITION] = T2.[POSITION] "
    
    objConn.Execute (strSQL)
    objConn.Close

    Set objConn = Nothing
End Sub

Code is written and tested using Excel 2010 64 Bit on Win 11 64 Bit
